# How to store hierarchical data in scipy?

Tags: scipy, hdf5

I am working with data analysis using the Scipy stack, and often have data with complicated hierarchies, e.g. dictionaries with elements as lists and again these lists have multiple dictionaries within them...

And therefore I have the need to store those data in a file. I have been using scipy.io.savemat, but I read that HDF5 is more suitable and less platform-specific (savemat is for Matlab).  The drawback is that with h5py, instead of saving variables in the workspace directly, I have to manually replicated the complicate structures (i.e. for each dictionary, I need to manually create_group accordingly).

Would there be a standard way to do this, like how we save ".mat" files in Matlab?

Thank you!

-Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to read your data back from python and don't need to change some bits of your data, it is much easier to save your things using pickle protocol.
E.g

```
import cPickle
f=open('something.pickle','w+')
cPickle.dump(whatever_object_youd_like_to_save,f,protocol=2)
```

and then you can load it using

```
your_object = cPickle.load(open('something.pickle'))
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I know that there should be something like this but it's not really intuitive for a newbie like me to know this - again thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

[joblib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib) is another tool that will let you dump arbitrary Python objects, with the added advantage of dedicated storage for NumPy arrays.